# Python print html output together with bootstrap modals

Tags: python, html, apache, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to do something very specific.

I have an Raspberry Pi2 with Apache2. I control with the raspberry Pi different ultrasonic sensors. The signals from the ultrasonic sensors are processed in a python program.

Depending on the values that I get back from the sensors, I write information in different strings. These strings are used to create my HTML file.

Afterwards, I send the HTML file with the print() command to Apache where my information gets displayed via the browser.

Now starts the confusing part. In these strings I use bootstrap modals. For example:

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
        style="width: 100%; height:100%; font-size:36px;"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">TEST</button>
<div class="modal fade"
     id="modal1"
     tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="modal1"
     aria-hidden="true"
     style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Check!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>TEST!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have already tested if these modals work on the Raspberry, and they do but only when I have pure HTML code. When I want to send exactly the same information to the server with a command, for example:

```
print ('%s'% test)
```

And the the test (test ="""....modal...""") strings contains exactly the same information, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: I have additionally now recognized that the behavior doesn't occur when the raspi is connected to the internet (of course are normally the paths for the modal usage to my local path adapted -> maybe is there my mistake?

Comment: Has been solved.
The problem was that apache had no access to my bootstrap files. I inserted the bootstrap folder in the var/www/html-folder and adapted the links. 
Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Has been solved. The problem was that apache had no access to my bootstrap files. I inserted the bootstrap folder in the var/www/html-folder and adapted the links. Anyway Thanks